# Jenkins Pipeline Groovy script. Script not found in workspace

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

The Jenkins is installed at Ubuntu. The Jenkins workspace is at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace. The github repo is at https://github.com/garyyang6/scripts. There are three scripts in the repo, build.sh, deploy.sh and quality.sh. The pipeline groovy script is as follow. After I ran the groovy script in Jenkins, it complains build.sh: not found.
At /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub, I found the scripts, build.sh  deploy.sh  quality.sh. The folder /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub@tmp is empty.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Git-Checkout') {
            steps {
                echo 'Checking out from Git Repo';
                git 'https://github.com/garyyang6/scripts.git'
            }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                     echo "Building the checked out project";
                     sh 'build.sh'
            }

        }
        stage('Unit-Test') {
            steps {
                echo "Running JUnit Tests";
            }
        }
        stage('Quality-Gate') {
            steps {
                echo "Verifying Quality Gates";
                sh 'quality.sh'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo "Deploying to Stage Environment for more tests";
                sh 'deploy.sh'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Erors:

```
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub@tmp/durable-9a8651c4/script.sh: 1: build.sh: not found
```

Comment: Do the scripts have executable permissions? Have you tried more explicit pathing to the scripts?

Comment: Yes. The scripts have executable permissions. Two folders generated at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace. They are Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub and Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub@tmp. In Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub, I found build.sh  deploy.sh  quality.sh. These scripts have executable permissions. The folder of Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub@tmp empty. The error complains cannot find the scripts at Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub@tmp. How to fix it?

/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub@tmp/durable-989858d2/script.sh: 1: build.sh: not found

Comment: You should have another directory in the workspace where the repo was cloned.

Comment: Yes. There are two directories in the workspace, /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub and /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub@tmp. "Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub@tmp " is empty. "build.sh" is in Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub. The error complains that cannot find build.sh in Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub@tmp. How to make Jenkins run the script at the directory Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub, not Scripted_Pipeline_GitHub@tmp?